# error using header(location:url) in zend

Tags: redirect, http-headers, zend-framework

In Zend I am using `header('Location: '.$redirect);` for redirection but it results in the following error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at /application/controllers/IndexController.php:160)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In zend:

You should use redirect in controller like this:

```
$this->_redirect('module/controller/action');
```

not in phtml file !

---

If you use only php+html:

Trim all white characters before redirection.

Probably you have some white character before the header location.

for example if you have html page

```
______ Start of page ____________

<?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); ?>

_________ end of page ___________
```

Before 'header( ... )' you have '\n\r' and there are already automatically set the header.